# Laravel json log with info/warn keywords

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I have implemented a custom json formatter extending from laravel's own json formatter. I have opted for stdout logging but its getting logged with extra keyword 'WARN' in the terminal but when I log it in the log file its directly logging without that keyword.

in the terminal:

> WARN {"method":"GET","uri":"/_health","route":null}

in the log file:

> {"method":"GET","uri":"/_health","route":null}

in my usecase I need the json output to be fed to the monitoring services but because of this 'WARN' keyword its coming as string.

PS: my log level is set to debug but every log is containing 'WARN' keyword only.

I expected a json output from the log but its coming as string with a keyword in prefix. I tried the internal jsonFormatter with stdout but its also logging the same.

Edit:

CustomJsonFormatter.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter;
use Monolog\LogRecord;

class CustomJsonFormatter extends JsonFormatter
{
    public function format(LogRecord $record): string
    {
        $formatted = $record['context'];

        if ($this->includeStacktraces) {
            $formatted['stack_trace'] = $record['formatted']['exception'];
        }

        return $this->toJson($formatted, true) . ($this->appendNewline ? "\n" : '');
    }
}
```

MethodLogChannel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter;
use App\Logging\CustomJsonFormatter;
use Monolog\Processor\IntrospectionProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor;

class MethodLogChannel
{
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
        $log = new Logger($config['name']);
        $handler = new StreamHandler($config['with']['path'], $config['with']['level']);
        $handler->setFormatter(new CustomJsonFormatter());
        $log->pushHandler($handler);
        $log->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor());
        $log->pushProcessor(new WebProcessor($_SERVER));
        return $log;
    }
}
```

channel in logging.php

```
    'methodlog' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via' => App\Logging\MethodLogChannel::class,
        'formatter' => App\Logging\CustomJsonFormatter::class,
        'name' => 'methodlog',
        'with' => [
            'path' => 'php://stdout',
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        ],
    ]
```

Comment: Maybe the issue on `MethodLogChannel() return $log;` will return with the keyword as a prefix.

Comment: But without `return $log;` it will not log any thing .... in the log file it is logging perfectly but in stdout it is occuring

Comment: Can you also share the code where you save the logs?

Comment: methodLog channel is directing the logs to the desired path ... there isn't any extra step for saving the logs

Comment: for ex: `Log::channel('methodlog')->info(['context'=>'Something happened!']);` this way you save logs?

Comment: my bad ... `Log::channel('methodlog')->info('', $log_message);` ... almost same as you mentiioned

Comment: Where does `$log_message` comes from?

Comment: `$log_message` is a basic array containing

`$log_message = ['log_level' => 'info','event_name' => $event_name, 'event_type' => $event_type, 'event_value' => $event_value, 'service' => $service, 'status_code' => $status_code, 'time' => $time, 'method' => $method, 'details' => $details];`

Comment: Basically for any `'php://stdout'` it is coming as ` WARN  someLog` only ... I tried with single and some other in built logging channels

Comment: Have you searched your code base for the text "WARN"? It sounds like custom debugging that was left in somewhere.

Comment: Yes I went through all the codebase but there isnt any `WARN` keyword anywhere