# Laravel stdout log adding extra keyword in log

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-artisan

I have tried with both inbuilt channels and custom ones as well whenever I am logging something in the terminal/stdout `WARN` keyword is added before the log.

[Laravel log in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og6nr.png)

but the same logs are coming as they are supposed to be in the log file
[Laravel log in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5veS.png)

in my use case I need the logs in json format in the terminal but because of the keyword it is coming as string.

This is logging method(I have tried the same with inbuilt channels like single ... but same)

```
        'methodlog' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via' => App\Logging\MethodLogChannel::class,
            'formatter' => App\Logging\CustomJsonFormatter::class,
            'name' => 'methodlog',
            'with' => [
                'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),//'php://stdout',
                'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            ],
        ],
```

Edit:
CustomJsonFormatter.php

```
class CustomJsonFormatter extends JsonFormatter
{
    private $DEFAULT_JSON_FLAGS = JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION | JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE | JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR ;
    public function format(LogRecord $record): string
    {
        $formatted = $record['context'];

        if ($this->includeStacktraces) {
            $formatted['stack_trace'] = $record['formatted']['exception'];
        }

        return $this->toJson($formatted, true) . ($this->appendNewline ? "\n" : '');
    }
}
```

MethodLogChannel.php

```
class MethodLogChannel
{
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
        $log = new Logger($config['name']);
        $handler = new StreamHandler($config['with']['path'], $config['with']['level']);
        $handler->setFormatter(new CustomJsonFormatter());
        $log->pushHandler($handler);
        $log->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor());
        $log->pushProcessor(new WebProcessor($_SERVER));
        return $log;
    }
}
```

for saving logs

> Log::channel('methodlog')->info('', $log_message);

Comment: You [already asked this today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76197784/laravel-json-log-with-info-warn-keywords), has something changed?

Comment: No .... couldn't get any solution over it .... asking it again

Comment: @brombeer any ideas over this?

Comment: Nope @AndyPreston, its my question only ....no leads there as well

Answer (score 0):

you can try customizing the format yourself for this channel:

```php
    'formatter' => Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter::class,
    'formatter_with' => [
        'format' => "%message%",
    ],
```

this should remove the other matchers, like :

- `%datetime%`
- `%channel%`
- `%level_name%` (this is the one in your question)
- `%message%`
- `%context%`
- `%extra%`

Comment: no its not level_name .... my level is set to debug